# What is wrong with this SQL query? (or perhaps why doesn't MySQL like the sixth field?)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my table:

```
id               int(11)
name             varchar(255)
description      text       
highest_bidder   int(11)
value            varchar(255)
group            int(11)
```

I originally didn't have the group field in there but added it later.

Anyway, I go to insert into the database using the following snippet:

```
INSERT INTO name_of_table_removed
(id,name,description,highest_bidder,group,value)
VALUES
(2,"...","...",0,3,"$45.99")
```

And I get an error:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group,value) VALUES (2,"...","...",0,3,"$45.99")' at line 1*

What am I missing?

Comment: Very bad approach with value field. it must be DECIMAL type and price must be stored without $ sign

Comment: @Col: I wondered when someone would criticize me for doing this - there is a very good reason for doing it that way. The price could potentially require more information like '$45 + tax' or who knows - maybe a different currency like £ or ¥. For that reason, it made sense to store as a string rather than a decimal.

Comment: it doesn't matter. normalize it in the database way. Both tax and currency must be stored separately.

Comment: George, I understand your reasoning. I also agree with Col. Shrapnel to a certain extent, although he could have been a little more helpful instead of just critical, especially since he doesn't even know how you're using your data. I recommend reading a database book to understand better how you should do things. I find C.J. Date's writing to be very accurate and authoritative. Until then, consider how you'll be using this data and whether this storage method will make that usage easy or difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group is a reserved word.  Escape the field as :

```
`group`
```

..Or rename the field.

Comment: Ah! I am such a idiot! That also explains why phpMyAdmin would work with it but my code could not.

Comment: Yep - tools like phpMyAdmin escape almost everything, just in case.

Comment: I noticed that it always did that... now I know why. Also, even SO picked up on the problem - look above and you can see that 'group' is highlighted as a reserved word.

Comment: I personally recommend escaping rather than renaming.  Otherwise, you may pollute your web application with things like $result->group_ .  Stop it at the source :)  By the way, in PostgreSQL, you would use double quotes (as in "group") instead of backticks.

Comment: It's okay. I renamed it to category and that is more in line with the app anyway.